# can I permanently add a way to sort my files in folders? and how do I do it?

Tags: windows-explorer

I like sorting my images by dimensions but every time I close the folder after adding the sort by dimensions option it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of windows, going to this option may be at a slightly different place.

What you do is first setup the folderview as you want it to be by default.

Then you go to the folder options (getting here is different for every windows version, but usually menu view-> options.)

Go to the tab view and press the button <kbd>Apply to all folders</kbd>.

This will set the current view settings as default. The button to the right <kbd>reset folders</kbd> can be used to undo this change.

*Due to my windows not being English, the wording might be slightly off. My apologies for the inconvenience.*